# I've created a connection between my SQL database and a WPF App but i want use an XML file and XDocument to connect them

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq-to-xml

To Start off i created a WPF App and an SQL Database  and successfully Parsed/connected them but my organization wants me to use a connection XML that connects from database to the App.(Preferably using.System.XML.Linq)
I hard coded it and I basically want to replace my hard coded connection with an XML connection

THE NAME of my XML is Connection.XML. The XML file is structured as so. The main tags <  configuration > </ configuration> contain the connection string in the < connectionString >< /connectionString > tags. Below them is the database name in < DataSource >< /DataSource>

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>Data Source=LAPTOP-ONETG0O\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Login; Integrated Security = true;</connectionStrings> 
<DataSource>Login</DataSource> 
</configuration>
```

This the App

public partial class LoginScreen : Window
{

```
    public LoginScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }


    

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-ONETG0O\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Login; Integrated Security = true");
        try
        {
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlCon.Open();
            String query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblUSER WHERE Username=@UserName AND Password=@Password";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUserName.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassWord.Password);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());

            if (count == 1)
            {
                MainWindow dashboard = new MainWindow();
                dashboard.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally { sqlCon.Close(); }
    }
    
       
    }
```

}

Comment: You can store the connection string and your Settings file (Project Properties). You should use `using` blocks to dispose the connection and command objects. I hope you aren't storing plain text passwords....

Comment: Please add to your question the actual XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Charlieface mentioned, connections are usually handled in the application's configuration XML file. Check it out here: [App.Config: Basics and Best Practices](https://blog.submain.com/app-config-basics-best-practices/)

Back to your custom made XML file. It is trivial via LINQ to XML.

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>Data Source=LAPTOP-ONETG0O\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Login; Integrated Security = true;</connectionStrings>
    <DataSource>Login</DataSource>
</configuration>
```

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\Temp\Connection.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
    string conn = xdoc.Descendants("connectionStrings").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    
    Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}", conn);
}
```

**Output**

```
ConnectionString: Data Source=LAPTOP-ONETG0O\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Login; Integrated Security = true;
```